# asp.net pages work, but classic asp gives access denied error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp-classic, iis-7

I am setting up an existing application on a new server. It is a mix of Asp.Net and Classic Asp pages. The asp.net pages work perfectly, but the classic asp pages give the following error:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or
>   access denied.

My Settings:

- Windows Server 2008 x64
- IIS7
- SQL 2008 Express with Advanced Services
- 32bit application

Here are some things I've tried:

- Set IIS7 AppPool to enable 32-bit applications
- Enabled "Active Server Pages" extension in IIS "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions"
- Installed Frontpage 2002 Extensions for IIS7 (from RTR)
- Enabled Named Pipes protocol in SQL Config Mgr

My Connection String:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=System;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=System;Password=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

My CLICONFG Alias:

- Server Alias = System
- Network Library = Named Pipes
- Connection Parameters = (local)

I've successfully installed the program in this environment before without any issues. Both `*.asp` and `asp.net` are using the same connection string, so I can't see how that is a problem. The User "System" specified in the Connection String is setup as a user in SQL with all permissions granted.

Please help!! I've spent over 3 days on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!!!

Thanks everyone for your assistance. I finally found the solution!

Turns out the connection string for my classic asp pages were expecting SQL to be installed with the default instance....but I had done a named instance. The connection string had "Data Source = System" (System was an alias setup on the computer that only specified (local) as the connection....it did not specify the instance name.).

I changed the connection string to "Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS" and it worked fine.

The connection string that was in there would have worked fine if I had selected "Default Instance" during the installation....as had been done on other servers I had installed.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that classic asp understands all the parameters in your connection string.  It likely ignores something it doesn't understand but the on that I think it's having the greatest trouble with is this one:

```
Data Source=(local)
```

and possibly

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I would try either:

1. Creating a second connection string and use one for classic ASP and the other for aspx. Use this 'simple' format for classic asp:

   ```
   Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
   ```
2. Change the Data Source parameter to use the actual server or instance name.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but unfortunately, I can't make any changes to the connection string (there are a few places this connection string is stored in the program, and I haven't found all of them). 

This setup has worked with this exact connection string for both asp.net and *.asp on *many* different servers. 

There is something in the server configuration that I am missing.

Comment: Fair enough.  You could at least try changing it as I advised to see if the classic ASP side works (even if it breaks the aspx side).   Also, perhaps you could refactor the classic ASP part of the app to pull the connection string from the web.config (instead of having it hardcoded into the app).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The connection string I had entered was the one from web.config. I guess asp.net uses that, but *.asp does not. The one for classic asp is as follows: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=mypassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=System;Initial Catalog=System;Data Source=System. "System" is setup as a Named Pipes Alias in CLICONFG set to (local). I've used this many times and never had trouble with classic asp. Not sure what I'm missing this time around.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.SqlClient` is a data provider for asp.net, it wouldn't work with classic asp.

Here's an example of a Classic ASP connection string for SQL Server

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=yourServerAddress;Initial Catalog=yourDataBase;User Id=yourUserid;Password=yourPwd;
```

For more examples see here - look at oledb providers.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Also, where are you putting your connection string?  If it's in web.config then .net will be able to read it but Classic ASP won't.  It needs to go in the page which wants to connect itself, in an include or in global.asa

Edit - one extra point.  If you're using SQL Server Express then you need to specify this - eg:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the clarification. I'm new to all of this. The program was written by someone else. The connection string I had put previously was in the web.config file...so it must be the one that asp.net is using, which is working fine. The one that *.asp is using is: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=mypassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=System;Initial Catalog=System;Data Source=System
The "Data Source=System" is directing to an alias setup in cliconfg with "System" set to Named Pipes, connected as (local). I've set it up this way on many other servers and haven't had an issue with *.asp

Comment: You could try changing your datasource in cliconfg to `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS`.  `localhost` sometimes doesn't work, It depends on whether or not the mapping is present in the hosts file, (which it usually is in out of the box Windows)

Comment: Thanks, John. I'll try that. Although this exact connection string has worked fine on the last 40 installations that we've done. I think it is something other than the connection string, but it won't hurt to give it a try. I appreciate your feedback. I'm really at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Shawnda, John and Evan make good suggestions and points.

I'll share my active live server configurations with you so you have something to test on your server. That's if you're running MSSQL on IIS 7.x and Windows 2008 Server with any flavor of SQL Server 2008.

I run 2 servers mixed .Net and ASP one Web 2008 and 2008 R2 with IIS .Net sites with ASP using a common db all sites mixed work just fine.

First tip, make your connection string a Call Function or Sub. 
From what you said you have to find all the locations you have your connection string.

How we migrate will help you. 
Create your function and place it into your SQL Included pages or your master scripts page that is included in all pages that need your connection string.

```
Function ConnOpen(SqlConn)
Dim strConnSql
Set SqlConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnSql = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBNAME;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD;"
SqlConn.Open strConnSql
End Function

Function ConnClose(SqlConn)
SqlConn.Close
Set SqlConn = Nothing
End Function
```

Follow what has been suggested and change the string. 
This is how I migrate sites from databases. 
I will add a new connection string as a function and test it on one of my pages. 
If the new connection works I'll do a search and replace of the string. 
Once you figure out which connection string works you're going to stop spending time like 3 days.

The string above is active on my .Net sites in my inc_sqlpage.asp which is included in all pages that require database connection.

You should find all your connection strings and remove and replace them with a easier to manage function.

```
Call ConnOpen(MyConn)
... 'your SQL 
Call ConnClose(MyConn)
```

If after this method you still can't connect then I'll say it's your server naming or firewall if this is a new server.

Example: I do not use IP address connections only internal DNS machine names. If i changed the servername to IP I would see the same type of error. 
I'm sure you have tried different settings but try the one above switching IP with Machine Name,  .\ and localhost but not (local).

Comment: Great comments, Let me give you the correct connection string that *.asp is using:  Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=mypass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=System;Initial Catalog=System;Data Source=System. "System" is a Named Pipes Alias in CLICONFG set to (local).....the firewall is disabled....I've enabled named pipes in SQL config manager, CLICONFG.  This is the exact same connection string that we've used on *many* other servers...including ones with the same Windows Server 2008 setup. I did change the Named Pipes from (local) to localhost\SQLEXPRESS, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005' 
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Comment: Shawnda, I was attempting to simulate what you have and didn't notice the  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" at the end of your connection string in your post. Is that string actually in your ASP file after your password=password" ? If so, remove it, add a ; after your password, change (local) to SQLEXPRESS or .\SQLEXPRESS and try it again. Below is what I think you are trying to do. 
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=DATABASEXXX;User ID=SYSTEM;Password=xxxx;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;"  The providerName= is ignored by ASP

Comment: Can you review your string and / or look at one of your servers that has a working string that you can verify for us? It just seems you have a mix of .Net and ASP in your connection string that just isn't going to work. Also, are you sure the named pipes approach is what you need on this server? (Just asking) Just remembered, the provider name you are attempting is .Net use either the SQLOLEDB or more specific SQLNCLI10 matching your SQLExpress.

Comment: @MurrayW It's worth mentioning that if you're using the native client provider you need to use the one which corresponds to the relevant version of MSSQL ie SQLNCLI11 for 2012, SQLNCLI10 for 2008, SQLNCLI for 2005

Comment: Good comment John, the OP mentioned the version so I stuck with the same. But it was good to point out for others that might skim over the OP. Like I did when I saw the .Net mixed with the ASP Connection string.

Comment: Thanks everyone. And thanks on the clarification of the SQLOLEDB vs SQLNCLI10 (etc...). I did not know that. I'm trying to see if I can get anything to work. I'll post back when I've tried everything that everyone has mentioned. Also, I think I'm going to delete and reinstall SQL, because I had a lot of trouble getting it to install originally (I had the wrong Microsoft download link). Anyone have any input on getting it to uninstall completely?